# Detecting if an iframe is empty or target unload-able

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've wrote a script that previews web pages within an iframe, the problem is that some pages (eg facebook and twitter) won't open within iframes.  Is it possible to detect if the page can't be loaded or if the iframe is empty?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible for sites that are not hosted on the same domain as yours, due to browsers [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

See if something like this would work for you

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hZZsS/)

```
alert($(".1").contents().find("body").length);
alert($(".2").contents().find("body").length);
```

Comment: not getting consistent results here and after the iframe has loaded I get cross origin errors when I use the command in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You will need send request to PHP script to check website headers. For example:

```
$.getJSON('http://debute.eu/allowed.php?url=' + url, function(data) { });
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/debute/5F7hT/).

If you can use PHP script, I will send you my PHP.